# force div height to nearest multiple of the background image height

Tags: javascript, css, background, background-image

Bit of a tricky situation to explain. Basically the overall image I'm trying to lay under my content div of my website is a messy box with grungy borders that bend in and out.

What I've got so far is something like this (irrelevant code removed)

```
<div class="content-top"><img src="content-top.png"></div>
<div id="content"> <!-- WORDPRESS LOADS CONTENT HERE --> </div>
<div class="content-bottom"><img src="content-bottom.png"></div>

CSS:
#content {
  background: url("assets/images/content-bg.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

the content-bg.png image is 300px high and is a repeatable image creating a patterned border either side.

The problem is the content-bottom.png image only looks right when placed at the end of one of these 300px tiles. If the page content is of a height that causes only half of the last background tile to be displayed the lines don't match up.

Typing this I doubt the answer lies in CSS and instead I'll need a javascript/jquery solution but as to the specifics of how to do so I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's asolution to your problem. It will *expand* the content container to the next height that is a *multiple of 300*.

**Plain JavaScript version**

```
var e = document.getElementById('content');
var height = e.clientHeight;
var newHeight = 300 * Math.ceil(height / 300);
e.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + newHeight + 'px;');
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/mHVGY/)

**jQuery version**

```
var e = $('#content');
e.css('height', 300 * Math.ceil(e.height() / 300));
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/AaxJn/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a i-can't-sleep-solution that supports a dynamic background image:

```
var content = $('#content'),
    height = content.height(),
    fixedImageHeight = null,     //.. number (pick one)
    srcImage = null,             //.. url to image (pick one)
    imageHeight = function() {
        return fixedImageHeight || function() {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = srcImage;
            return image.height;
        }();
    }(),
    neededPadding = (height > imageHeight) 
        ? height % imageHeight
        : imageHeight - height;

content.height(height + neededPadding);
```